# Replace pattern with digit for html class

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

i have a html like this:

```
<td class="TableDetail1 itemNumber">1</td>
<td class="TableDetail1 itemNumber">2</td>
<td class="TableDetail1 itemNumber">3</td>
```

how to use replace to match the pattern above and change the **1/2/3** numbering?
my javascript look like this:

```
 x.innerHTML = x.innerHTML.replace(/<td class="TableDetail1 itemNumber">+document.getElementsByClassName('itemNumber')[lastRow].innerHTML+<\/td>/g,  '<td class="TableDetail1 itemNumber">'+numbering+'</td>');
```

but it did not work.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: because i want to replace the current html's numbering with calculated number

Comment: Forget using a regular expression. You've shown what you currently have but not what you want it to look like after transformation. Add that to your question

Comment: What is your expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i come out a solution with this:

```
 x.innerHTML = x.innerHTML.replace('<td class="TableDetail1 itemNumber">'+currentRow+'</td>',  '<td class="TableDetail1 itemNumber">'+numbering+'</td>');
```

this seem work..